# Why Nginx is Serving my django app in port 8000 instead of 80?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

i have created a app using django . I run this application now using
django compose build
django compose up .

When i open  http://0.0.0.0:8000 its coming with static files. when i open http://0.0.0.0:80 its not showing me static files

**Docker compose **

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn

volumes:
  static:
```

Docker File

```
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./video_app /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Entry.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py migrate --no-input
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=$SUPER_USER_PASSWORD python manage.py createsuperuser --username $SUPER_USER_NAME --email $SUPER_USER_EMAIL --noinput

gunicorn video_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

NGINX Docker file

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Default.conf

```
upstream django {
    server django_gunicorn:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nakik.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78CmZ.png)

Could you please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Your default.conf file only lists Django's docker address, but it doesn't list the port, so it defaulted to port 80. Change it to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:8000;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```